# How can a syslog configuration be set to place a log in the users home directory?

Tags: files, permissions, non-root-user, syslog

I want to use one of Drupal's syslog modules but place the log in a the user's home directory so there are not permissions issues when the user wants to view or analyze the file.

Is there a way a syslog configuration can be set in that way?

Comment: what syslog daemon are you using?

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep syslog` produces `rsyslog   8.24.0-1 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a file to route wanted messages to a given user directory. Eg create `/etc/rsyslog.d/00-meuh.conf` with

```
if ($msg contains "testing") then {
  action(type="omfile" file="/home/meuh/logs/meuh-rsyslog" sync="on" fileCreateMode="0644" fileOwner="meuh")
  stop
}
```

then restart rsyslog and send a suitable message with

```
$ sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
$ logger 'meuh testing new logfile'
```

The file is created:

```
$ ls -l /home/meuh/logs/meuh-rsyslog
-rw------- 1 meuh root 50 Sep 23 17:10 /home/meuh/logs/meuh-rsyslog
$ cat /home/meuh/logs/meuh-rsyslog
Sep 23 17:10:22 home meuh: meuh testing new logfile
```